# what field should I use for inline svg?

Tags: prismic.io

Example:

[image]

I'm trying to model this in prismic, but I don't know how to add this arrow icon, I know I can add an image but I don't want to because I want to add inline svg, any idea how to handle this ?

should i just add 2 fields for the text and skip modeling the icon and add it in the front end ?

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Prismic here! In this case I'd definitely add it to the front end. Especially if this is something that this component should always have and the editors shouldn't be able to add their own image.

Also for using the inline SVG, there's not a better way to handle that in most CMS's than an image field or adding it to the front end.